# Calculate difference between two values (python)

Tags: python, difference

If I have a variable x that returns a bunch of numbers (floats), how can I calculate the difference between all the adjacent numbers (e.g. (x - x-1), (x-1 - x-2) until the last term?).

Comment: Can you show some code? I don't understand how "a variable x [can] return a bunch of numbers (floats)"... Do you mean `x` is an array?

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you've written down in your question.  The answer is there staring at you.

```
[x[i+1]-x[i] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

One of the nicest things about python is that is has *declarative*   features. You can often get what you want by just describing it; you don't always have to explicitly give the recipe.